# Golang SSH tunneling and ProxyJump

Tags: linux, go, ssh, ssh-tunnel

What I need is to perform the equivalent of the following command but in Go code:

```
ssh -L 9999:192.168.1.1:80 -J root@[IPv6 address] myuser@100.1.1.100
```

I'm not even sure where to start with this one.
I haven't been able to find any examples online and I'm at a loss.

Does anyone know how this could be done in Go?

Answer (score 3):

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "log"
    "net"

    "golang.org/x/crypto/ssh"
)

func main() {
    client, err := ssh.Dial("tcp", "100.1.1.100:22", &ssh.ClientConfig{
        User:            "root",
        Auth:            []ssh.AuthMethod{ssh.Password("")},
        HostKeyCallback: ssh.InsecureIgnoreHostKey(),
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Panicln(err)
        return
    }
    log.Println("init ssh client")

    ln, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":9999")
    if err != nil {
        log.Panicln(err)
        return
    }
    log.Println("local listen")

    for {
        localconn, err := ln.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            log.Panicln(err)
            return
        }

        sshconn, err := client.DialTCP("", nil, &net.TCPAddr{IP: net.ParseIP("192.168.1.1"), Port: 80})
        if err != nil {
            log.Panicln(err)
            return
        }

        // local <--> remote
        go func() {
            errc := make(chan error, 1)
            spc := switchProtocolCopier{user: localconn, backend: sshconn}
            go spc.copyToBackend(errc)
            go spc.copyFromBackend(errc)
            log.Printf("stop conn error: %v\n", <-errc)
        }()
    }
}

// switchProtocolCopier exists so goroutines proxying data back and
// forth have nice names in stacks.
type switchProtocolCopier struct {
    user, backend io.ReadWriter
}

func (c switchProtocolCopier) copyFromBackend(errc chan<- error) {
    _, err := io.Copy(c.user, c.backend)
    errc <- err
}

func (c switchProtocolCopier) copyToBackend(errc chan<- error) {
    _, err := io.Copy(c.backend, c.user)
    errc <- err
}
```